# Algebra Combination Lock

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given a combinaiton lock problem for my college math class, and at a first glance it seems elementary but I just cannot wrap my mind around it. the problem is as follows:

$$a+c=8$$
    $$d-c=4$$
    $$d-a=2$$
    $$c-b=-1$$
the problem is to solve for $a$,$b$,$c$, and $d$. short of substituting every possible combination I cannot see how I am supposed to find even a single letter. Once I have found a single letter the rest seems as if it would fall in to place. Perhaps it is because I have been up late on the night before the test but I cannot see the solution.

Comment: If you add the first two equations, you now have $$a + d = 12 \quad d = a + 2$$ Do you see how to proceed now?

Comment: wow that was pretty simple

Answer (score 1):

The general purpose answer is to solve one equation for a variable, then substitute that expression in all the other equations.  You now have one less equations in one less variable.  Then keep going, and you will have one equation in one variable, which you hope to be able to solve.  If they are all linear you will succeed.  Sometimes there is a shortcut.  In your case, you could notice that $b$ is only in the last equation, so you have $b=c+1$ and you already don't have $b$ anywhere else, so you are down to three equations in three unknowns.  Again in this case, you could add the first two equations to eliminate $c$ and use that with the third as two equations in two unknowns.  If you don't see that, you could write the third as $a=d-2$ and put $d-2$ in for $a$ in the first one.  Now the first two have only $c,d$ as variables.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting the 32d equation from the 2nd gives you a-c=2

Thus, you get simultaneous equations in a and c solving which gives you the values of a and c as a=5, c=3. Just substitute this in the subsequent equations to get d=7, b=4.

Hope this helps!